# MySQL try-catch not working properly

Tags: c#, mysql, exception

I'm trying to catch `error 1045 (access denied)` from MySQL, but i'm having some weird issues.. Is there something wrong with my code ?

Instead of handling the exception it throws me one in VS ?

```
private bool connOpen()
{
    bool kleir = false;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        kleir = true; // throws exception here
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        switch (ex.Number)
        {
            case 1045:
                MainWindow.connError = true;
                break;
        }
        kleir = false;
    }
    return kleir;
}
```

Comment: Comment out the `kleir = true;` line and see if it still throws the error.

Comment: @Brian still the same issue, i even tried just using `return false` and `return true` instead of `bool kleir`. But it won't enter the `catch` block, it stays in the `try` block :/

Comment: What is the exception error message? Add a Console.WriteLine(ex.Message) before the switch

Comment: @DeMama - Also, are you _sure_ that your connection is initialized?  I don't see a declaration for it in the code above.

Comment: @Steve error message is `Message: Access denied for user '%s'@'%s' (using password: %s)` (taken from mysql manual), i'm handling this exception on purpose for testing purposes. even VS is giving me `1045` in `errorCode` from MySQL.. It won't enter my catch block

Comment: @Brian My connection initializes somewhere else so that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: So the problem is in the conn.Open not in the assignement of true to a boolean variable. I think you should check what values you have in the Exceptions dialog from menu DEBUG -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions. Something has been changed there because the exception should go to the catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the exception is thrown when you try to open the connection, but the Dialog in menu `DEBUG.Exceptions.Common Language Runtime Exceptions` has the checkbox marked under the column `Thrown`. This should be the reason why your code stops at the line shown and do not enter the catch block

Comment: Yes this was the problem, the only weird thing my error message is equal to the `1045` error. But now `errorCode` is telling me 0 instead of `1045`.. Weird !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are debugging this in VS.  VS will stop on the exception even though you have an exception handler *because* you are in debug mode.  If you run this outside of studio, then the exception will be handled by the block.  You should also be able to simply hit F5 (Run) in order to continue.

But that, in my opinion, is just a side show.  The code you've shown is pretty bad.  This snippet implies that you are opening a single connection, using that to make one or more DB calls, then somewhere along the way you have another method to close it.

You should never initialize/manage connections away from where you are actually using them.  The connection pool is more than capable of properly handling a large number of connect/disconnects.  The reason you should keep that code together is simply that the more things in between open/close on the connection then the more opportunities your code has of not properly disposing of those objects.  When they aren't disposed of then the connection pool will crater with very odd and difficult to debug issues and memory usage goes way up.

The connection and command database objects are unmanaged objects.  They implement IDisposable because they control unmanaged resources.  An example of the right way of doing this is:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring)) {
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(conn)) {
    // do atomic database stuff
  }
}
```

The using statements will automatically close and dispose of those objects.  The connection pool (that you don't even have to think about) will ensure that if you call the above code 1000 times, that it still runs super fast.

Comment: +1, i already knew the using trick, and maybe i'll consider changing my code to using blocks. But this may come in handy for programmers that are new with MySQL in .NET